# Generic Repository - Array of Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> Error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I have a generic Include method in a Entity Framework Generic Repository wrapper.

```
public IQueryable<T> Include<T, TProperty>(IQueryable<T> queryable, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> property)
    {
        return queryable.Include(property);
    }
```

It works great, however it is only good for one include.

```
var result = this.Context.RP.Include(query, r => r.Country);
```

I would like a method where i have a list of Expressions, so that multiple includes can be given.

```
 var result = this.Context.RP.Includes(query, r => r.Country, r => r.Country.Provinces, r=> r.Country.Languages);
```

I created the following method and similar, but will either get the error "Cannot convert lambda expression to type cecause it is not a delegate type" or "The type arguments for method  cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly."

```
public IQueryable<T> Includes<T>(IQueryable<T> queryable, Expression<Func<T, Object>>[] predicates)
    {
         foreach (var predicate in predicates)
             queryable.Include(predicate);

        return queryable;
    }
```

Is there a correct way to have multiple Lambda expression a parameter here?

Comment: Why do you need that? Do you know that if you write Include(r => r.Country.Provinces), Country gets automatically included? It also returns back the queryable thus providing a fluent api so you can easily write .Include(r => r.Country.Provinces).Include(r => r.Country.Langs). It kinda seems like you are reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Sometimes, i need to include different relationship in the same wrapper statement .Include(r => r.Country) && .Include(r => r.Languages) && .Include(r => Taxes.Hst). But yes, it does seem like reinventing the wheel, i would prefer to just directly use the EF Fluent API, but team does not want EF exposed directly, instead use a Generic wrapper to interact with EF.

Answer (score 4):

I would use a `params` keyword to mark the parameter as a size-variable array.

Also, I would re-assign `queryable` at every iteration:

```
public IQueryable<T> Includes<T>(IQueryable<T> queryable, params Expression<Func<T, Object>>[] paths)
{
    if (paths == null || paths.Length <= 0)
        return queryable;

    foreach (var path in paths)
    {
        queryable = queryable.Include(path);
    }

    return queryable;
}
```